# Remove needless repetition of words from a text including repeated words with apostrophes

Tags: vimscript, replace

This expression, run interactively within Vim:

```
:%s/ \v(\w+('\w+)*)\_s\1/ \1/gi
```

It removes needless repetition of words.

In this way it turns this:

```
the the it it them them it's it's then then and this too
```

into this:

```
the it them it's then and this too
```

as intended.

However the same expression used within vimscript, like this,

```
silent! exe ':%s/ \v(\w+('\w+)*)\_s\1/ \1/gi'
```

fails to replace any repeated words.

I have tried:

- escaping the `'` with a preceeding `'`
- escaping the `'` with a preceeding `\`
- enclosing the expression in double quotes `":%s .... "` and not escaping the `'`

but none of these worked.

I also tried:

```
silent! exe ':%s/ \v(\w+('\''\w+)*)\_s\1/ \1/gi'
```

This did not work either.

Comment: Why do you use `:help :execute` to begin with? `:help :s` is perfectly valid in vimscript on its own.

Comment: exactly, there is no reason to make your life harder and trying to put it into and `:exe` string.

Comment: The title of the question should be rephrased. It's not about removing this and that, it's about fixing a vimscript expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remark of @romainl and @christianbrabandt are of course very valid.

But if you insist to use the `execute` command you have two possibilities:

1. Use the literal vimscript string (`'`) where you escape `'` with another `'` (i.e. `''`)

```
silent! execute '%s/\v(\w+(''\w+)*)\_s\1/\1/gi'
```

2. Use the non-literal vimscript string (`"`) where you have to escape `\` with another `\` (i.e. `\\`)

```
silent! execute "%s/\\v(\\w+('\\w+)*)\\_s\\1/\\1/gi"
```

Comment: THANK YOU! None of the other proposals worked. Why? I don't know. The only thing that worked was this `silent! execute "%s/ \\v(\\w+('\\w+)*)\\_s\\1/ \\1/gi"`. Appreciated ! ps it would be great if `:%s .... ' worked. I'm sure it's suppose to, but I couldn't get it going for this expression.